# Java generic class syntax

Tags: java

I know that I can create a class in java like this:

```
public class test {/*some code*/}
```

But now I have this:

```
public class coada < T extends Number & Comparable < Number>> {
    List <T> pq = new ArrayList <T>();

    public void add(T e , List <T> c) {
        c.add(e);
        Collections.sort(c);
    }

    public void remove(List < ? extends Number> c) {
        c.remove(0);
    }
}
```

I don't understand the more complicated syntax of the angled brackets and parameter lists.

I have these questions:

1. Can someone clarify the syntax used in the example?
2. I know Java doesn't support multiple inheritance.
   So how are Number & Comparable possible?
3. I thought generics are used for collections, not classes,
   so, how can `class coada` have a type parameter?

Comment: Recommended reading: [*The Java(tm) Tutorials: Lesson: Generics (Updated)*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/)

Comment: Do you see that `Comparable`is an interface and not a class?

Comment: edit your question and select code and press ctrl-M not use br

Comment: When posting questions, you don't use HTML tags, it is WYSIWYG style.

Answer (score 2):

1. `T extends Number & Comparable <Number>`
   T extends Number and implements Comparable
2. Generics don't require type to be a collection.

Answer (score 1):

`Comparable` is an interface, so `T` can extend `Number` and implement `Comparable<Number>` (and any number of other interfaces) at the same time.

As for your second question, any class can have type parameters, not only `Collection`s. `coada < T extends Number & Comparable < Number>>` means that the class `coada` has a type parameter called T which must be either `Number` or a sub-class of `Number` and implement the interface `Comparable<Number>`.

Comment: ??? interfaces are implemented not extended so you still didn't explained the sintax extend Number & Comparable . that is what i asked... And also you didn't explained how class coada have a type parameter .... so what do you want to prove? i am a biginer . if you don't explain it clear just don't pls

Comment: @MyUserQuestion Sorry, I missed your second question and only answered the first one.